# Why .Net Maui entries padding is different between Windows and Android?

Tags: maui

I have .Net Maui page with some entries.

When running the app in Windows, the entries have padding. However in android physical device, there is no padding.

Here is my page code (nothing fancy):

```
        <VerticalStackLayout IsVisible="{Binding AccessStaffMode}" Margin="20">
            <Entry x:Name="InputIdentifiant" MaxLength="20" Placeholder="Identifiant"/>
            <Entry x:Name="InputPassword_StaffMode" MaxLength="20" Placeholder="Password"/>
            <Entry x:Name="InputSecurityCode" MaxLength="20" Placeholder="Security code" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
```

In Windows it shows as:

[image]

In Android physical device, it shows as:

[image]

How can I correct that? I need the padding in all platforms in my entries.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bug. I suggest you report [a bug](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new?assignees=&labels=t%2Fbug&template=bug-report.yml) in the MAUI repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Handlers` in MAUI, just like the renderer in xamarin.

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Platform;

namespace CustomizeHandlersDemo;

public partial class CustomizeEntryPage : ContentPage
{
    public CustomizeEntryPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ModifyEntry();
    }

    void ModifyEntry()
    {
        Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (handler, view) =>
        {
#if ANDROID
            handler.PlatformView.SetBackgroundColor(Colors.Transparent.ToPlatform());
#elif IOS
            handler.PlatformView.BorderStyle = UIKit.UITextBorderStyle.None;
#elif WINDOWS
            handler.PlatformView.FontWeight = Microsoft.UI.Text.FontWeights.Thin;
#endif
        });
    }
}
```

In the `ModifyEntry` method you can customize an entry on different platform.

More details you can refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize).